# XenServer libguestfs

Tags: xenserver

I am using XenServer 6.5 and I want to mount, modify disk partitions of VHD disk format created by XenServer. 
For this purpose I need to get libguestfs running as libguestfshas the required features. I have used libguestfs on KVM.
Now XenServer modifies the CentOS repos.
I tried to use EPEL for RHEL 5 to add libguestfs but there are lots of depsolving issues.
Has anyone been able to use libguestfs on XenServer ?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to add a comment above, but "You must have 50 reputation to comment", which is dumb.  I suggest posting the full depsolving messages to our mailing list (libguestfs at redhat.com).  You don't have to subscribe to it.